# SASS; change font-family if size of element is above 16px

Tags: node.js, automation, sass, gruntjs, right-to-left

I don't even know if this is possible, I have to bring an RTL version of the website that is LTR.. I'm using Foundation 5 with Node and Grunt.Basically a file that overwrites some css rules of the original ltr file..

The client asked me to; Use a special font-family when the size of the element's text is above 16px.. Since other devs change the sass/css constantly I need a tool (or SASS formula) that allows to automatically switch the font-family when deploying the files with Grunt.

So instead of spending lots of time "scanning" the whole css/sass files for font-sizes and re-creating those rules with correct font-family.. I need something that automatically detects if the font-size is set then checks if it is above 16px, then if so, it changes the font family of the element.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me best way to do that is to use one `SASS` mixin to apply the `font-size` and check the value to apply the custom font :

```
@mixin custom-font-size($pixel) {

    font-size: $pixel;
    @if $pixel > 16 {
        font-family: 'Comic Sans MS';
    }
}
```

and call it like so :

```
@include custom-font-size(10px);
```

Comment: Merci @Apercus ! Where should I call it? in every SASS element/declaration?

Comment: Yes, if you want to apply the custom font depending on the size on an element, you have to include the custom mixin on it.